# thread safe processing of a queue

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I am putting tasks from the UI-thread into a queue, so that they can be processed in another thread. if there is nothing to do, the thread should wait with an `AutoResetEvent` - obviously all this should be threadsafe.

i am putting tasks in the queue from the UI-thread like this:

```
lock (_syncObject)
{
    _queue.Enqueue(new FakeTask());
}

    _autoResetEvent.Set();
```

here is how my processing thread-loop looks so far:

```
while (true)
{
    FakeTask task = null;
    lock (_syncObject)
    {
        if (_queue.Count > 0)
        {
            task = _queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }

    if (task != null)
    {
        task.Run();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);  //just here for testing purposes
    }

    if (_queue.Count == 0)
    {
        _autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

i am afraid that the last part where i check if something else is in the queue is not thread safe and would like to know how i can make it so. thanks!

Comment: You could use a [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) rather than handling the lock yourself

Comment: at first i also thought about `ConcurrentQueue`, but doesnt this one just lock the `Enqueue` and `Dequeue` methods? i still would miss a racecondition where something gets added between the last two lines?

Comment: If you use `TryPeek` rather than the count. You could also look at the [Producer Consumer pattern using the Dataflow library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-a-producer-consumer-dataflow-pattern) to see if that would better suit your needs

Comment: Have a look at `BlockingCollection` which has been specially designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *simple case*, try using [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) which has been *specially designed* for implementing [Producer / Consumer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem):

```
private async Task Process() {
  using (BlockingCollection<FakeTask> _queue = new BlockingCollection<FakeTask>()) {
    Task producer = Task.Run(() => {
      while (!completed) {
        //TODO: put relevant code here 
        _queue.Add(new FakeTask());
      }

      _queue.CompleteAdding();
    });

    Task consumer = Task.Run(() => {
      foreach (FakeTask task in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
        //TODO: process task - put relevant code here
      }
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer).ConfigureAwait(false); 
  }
}
```

**Edit:** if `producer` is *UI thread* itself:

```
private async Task Process() {
  using (BlockingCollection<FakeTask> _queue = new BlockingCollection<FakeTask>()) {
    Task consumer = Task.Run(() => {
      foreach (FakeTask task in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
        //TODO: process task - put relevant code here
      }
    });

    // If we produce in UI we don't want any separate Task 
    while (!completed) {
      //TODO: put relevant code here 
      _queue.Add(new FakeTask());
    }

    _queue.CompleteAdding();

    await consumer.ConfigureAwait(false); 
  }
}
```

In case of *entangled mesh* (e.g. producers #1, #2 genetate tasks for consumers #1, #2, #3 which in turn create tasks for...) try [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow?view=netcore-2.1)

Comment: thanks, the only speciality about my case is that the tasks must be executed in the same order as they have been added and not in paralell. is this guaranteed with this solution?

Comment: @oleole: tasks will be consumed *in order* (first come - first consumed), this is a default behaviour of `BlockingCollection`

Comment: ok thanks, i was just wondering this because the documentation says there is a constructor offering to wrap a ConcurrentQueue. if order is guaranteed anyway, why is this needed?

Comment: @oleole: for *flexibility*: you can provide your own backing collection (e.g. *stack*, *priority query* etc.) which can be useful in many cases

Answer (score -1):

It's not useful to create a thread just so that it can spend basically all of its time sitting around doing nothing waiting for work to do.

All you need to do is use an asynchronous locking mechanism around the UI task's scheduling of background work to be done.  `SemaphoreSlim` provides such an asynchronous synchronization mechanism.

```
await sempahoreSlim.WaitAsync();
try
{
    await Task.Run(() => DoWork());
}
finally
{
    sempahoreSlim.Release();
}
```

Not only is it a lot less code, and has much simpler code that more accurately reflects what the business logic of the application is, but you're consuming quite a lot less system resources.

And of course if different background operations can safely run in parallel, then just use the thread pool, rather than your own message loop, and the code becomes even simpler.